# All dropdown rows open on click

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am working on a component for a gatsby project.
I want to build a dropdown menu component that shows data about teachers that teach the subject selected.
this is how it looks like right now:

[image]

Actually everything works, except that all dropdown rows will open when one is clicked. I just want the one to open that is selected.

Take a look at my code below:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { BiChevronDown } from "react-icons/bi";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"


const rows = [
    {
    id: "verantwortliche",
    title: "Verantwortliche",
    },
    {
    id: "streichinstrumente",
    title: "Lehrende der Streichinstrumente",

    },
    {
    id: "zupfinstrumente",  
    title: "Lehrende der Zupfinstrumente",

    },
    {
    id: "tasteninstruments",    
    title: "Lehrende des Tasteninstruments",
    },
    {
    id: "gesangs",  
    title: "Lehrende des Gesangs",
    },
    {
    id: "schlagzeugs",  
    title: "Lehrende des Schlagzeugs",
    },
    {
    id: "akkordeons",   
    title: "Lehrende des Akkordeons",
    },
    {
    id: "musiktheorie", 
    title: "Lehrende der Musiktheorie",
    },
    {
    id: "frueherziehung",   
    title: "Lehrende der Früherziehung",
    }
]



function Departments(props) {
    return(
    <article>
        <div className="staff-image-container">
        <GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={props.image} style={{margin: "0 auto", padding: "0"}} />
        </div>
        <div style={{margin: "0 2em"}}>
        <div>
            <h4 style={{margin: "0"}}>{props.name}</h4>
            <h5>{props.description}</h5>
        </div>
        <p><MDXProvider>{props.bio}</MDXProvider></p>
        </div>
    </article> 
    )
}



class DropDownRows extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: false};
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    console.log(id);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn,
        selectedCategory: id
    }));
    }
    handleSelect(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    console.log(id);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedCategory: id
    }));
    }

    
    render() {
    return (
        <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query departmentsQuery {
        allMdx {
            edges {
            node {
                excerpt(pruneLength: 900)
                id
                body
                            fileAbsolutePath
                frontmatter {
                                id
                title
                description
                featuredImage {
                    childImageSharp {
                    gatsbyImageData(
                        placeholder: BLURRED
                    )
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }       
        `}

        render={data => (
            <div className="dropdown-rows">
            {rows.map(row => (
                <div key={row.id}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">{row.title}</div>
                    <div className="col">
                    <BiChevronDown
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        style={{float: "right"}}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                        id={row.id}
                    />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="staff-container">               
                    {data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => (
                    this.state.isToggleOn && this.state.selectedCategory && row.id  == edge.node.frontmatter.id
                        ? <Departments id={edge.node.id} name={edge.node.frontmatter.title} description={edge.node.frontmatter.description} key={edge.node.id} image={getImage(edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage)}  bio={edge.node.excerpt} />
                    : ''
                    ))}
                </div>
                </div>
            ))}
            </div>
        )}
        />
    )
    }
}

export default DropDownRows
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be in this line

```
this.state.isToggleOn && this.state.selectedCategory && row.id  == edge.node.frontmatter.id
```

You are checking id in wrong way, you should check like

```
this.state.isToggleOn && this.state.selectedCategory == row.id
```

Because in your approach if `selectedCategory` exist you let to open all childrens not just the one with `id` match